# How to upload images using REST API and C#

Tags: c#

I am using php REST API and C# to post an image along with access token by using RestSharp, sending image file and access token as parameters but i unable to achieve with this below sample program

```
 private static void postPrescription(string ext, string mime, string token)
    {
        var restClient = new RestClient("http://api.xxy.in/v1/docsupload");
        restClient.AddHandler("application/octet-stream", new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer());
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("client-Identifier", "192.168.1.24");
        request.AddHeader("client-Platform", "kiosk");
        request.AddHeader("client-Version", "2.00");
        request.AddHeader("client-Type", "kiosk");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict.Add("FILE_EXT", ext);
        dict.Add("FILE_MIME_TYPE", mime);
        byte[] imageBytes;
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Prescriptions\Presc_1_10_2015_17_19_17.jpeg", FileMode.Open))
        {
            imageBytes = new BinaryReader(fs).ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        }
        string image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        dict.Add("IMAGE_DATA", image);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict));
        request.AddParameter("access_token", token);
        request.AddParameter("userfile", data);
        var response = restClient.Execute(request);
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, object> dict1 = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(response.Content);

    }
```

While trying with above snippet i got a response as 
"{\"response\":400,\"message\":\"File not supported\"}"

After this I tried using HTTP POST method but not succeeded, i got http response as "{\"response\":401,\"message\":\"You have been logged out to protect your privacy. Please log back in.\"}"

This is my second snippet,

```
  public static void prescriptionPost(string token)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.xxy.in/v1/docsupload");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequestHeaders(httpWebRequest);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        byte[] imageBytes;
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Prescriptions\Presc_1_10_2015_17_19_17.jpeg", FileMode.Open))
        {
            imageBytes = new BinaryReader(fs).ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        }
        string image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(image));
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            pres ps = new pres
            {
                access_token = token,
                userfile = image
            };
            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ps, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }


        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var myobj = serializer.Deserialize<ObtainToken>(result);
        }

       // example deserializedProduct = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<example>(json);
    }

 internal class pres
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string userfile { get; set; }
}
```

I dont know whether my snippets are correct or there was a problem exists in RestApi
Can anyone suggest me that how can i achieve this.

Comment: Does it work when you upload images in browser? If so, use a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to see how your requests are different from browser requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
using RestSharp;

byte[] imgdata = ImageFileToByteArray(@"D:\SampleIMG.jpg");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("URL", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("secret_key", "secret_key_data");
request.AddParameter("Name_Key","Mahesh");
request.AddFile("imageKey", imgdata, "SampleIMG.jpg", "image/jpeg");
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
```